how to make a expo app in a monorepo work on android?
I try to make expo work on a monorepo.
But when I try to make it work with this documentation :
https://docs.expo.dev/guides/monorepos/
I don't really get the same result on each device.

on ios everything work fine
on android we have nothing

the screen look like this
I have setup the metro.config.js and the EXPO_USE_METRO_WORKSPACE_ROOT=1

here the repo to test it.
https://github.com/pikooli/expo-mono
Does anyone have a solution ?
